# New D8 / Civi install. First d8 then added Civi. Civi Menus not showig up

Tags: civicrm-home, drupal-8

I installed D8 first then Civi and it seems like it is working if I manually put the url comonents after the [http://focal-civi.domain.org/civicrm/{manually-add}](http://focal-civi.domain.org/civicrm/%7Bmanually-add%7D) but the menu is not showing up.

Anyone have any hints?

[image: No Menu]

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser dev-tools console? What do you have in civicrm.settings.php for $civicrm_root and overrides for $civicrm_paths - does it match your actual paths?

Comment: I'll check those settings and logs and report back.  Of note, if I use the RoundEarth as the core then it works but if I use the Drupal-Reco Base then it doesn't.

Comment: Oh man, there are a lot of errors when I click the CiviCRM menu..,.,.  A lot.  Trying to figure out how to post it...

Comment: Here is a google doc with the error log https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ALMoWcjwNxu2iZEBD6Kph-55ZJss-Q-7Yjy_3vuHpIo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You can also edit your original question and paste there  but what it looks like is each of those resources is returning drupal's error page (hence the text/html). If you visit one of the links do you see the actual error? Or in drupal watchdog?

Answer (score 2):

I think I just responded to you on GitLab. From what you described there I think you may need to:

`composer civicrm:publish`

to populate `web/libraries`

Comment: I tried that with no help.  I can get the menu to work loading Civi on top of a standard D8 install but at least two distributions (Lightning and Varbase) cause the menu to stop working.  It looks like the menu pops up for a very short time then the standard Drupal Toolbar slides up over top of it.

Comment: This helped me populate the /web/libraries/civicrm folder. First, you have to make it writable for the user running the group. Thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

This problem was (I think) related to a permission problem with the plug-in not having permissions to copy the libraries from a parent directory to the doc-root directory.

Solved for me.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Also for me (in addition to directory permissions) is the fact that some distributions use different names for their docroot directory.

Core uses ./web
Varbase uses ./docroot
OpenSocial uses ./html

This can be accounted for if you add this to the composer.json in the extras section

```
 "civicrm-asset": {
     "path": "***docroot***/libraries/civicrm",
     "url": "/libraries/civicrm"
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar on a Backdrop site and it turned out to be caused by the way I had set up the directory structure.

I was trying to get fancy using a symlink and the server was using the symlink as the website's document root, but in the `civicrm.settings.php` I was pointing to the other directory. Changing the settings file to also point to the symlink solved it.